# How can I escape the destiny of a soap bubble?

Tags: magic

In 24 hours time, every person alive today will turn into a soap bubble. This process is inevitable and irreversible, where must I be and what can I do if I wanna be the last one to pop? I'll applaud the answer that allow me to go around the world in eighty days without popping!(this question is not for the faint of heart)

The surface area of the bubble is equal to the surface area of the skin. The surface tension of each bubble is 25 dyn/cm and this is a constant.

Comment below if you disagree with the constant.

Comment: This seems to be off-topic to worldbuilding. But could be an on-topic question for the [puzzling site](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com). However, it would still be probably considered as low quality there, even if on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Find an accessible [industrial freezer room](http://www.cszindustrial.com/Products/Industrial-Freezers/Bio-Store-Freezer-Rooms.aspx), gain access to it with lots of money (don't hold back, humans typically have little use for money after bubblification) and/or pretext of a sexual fetish, have it set to the lowest possible temperature, close the door so no air currents can enter. Set up a large tent to guard against air currents generated by the freezer room. Set up a kiddie pool inside the tent, with a little bit of water in it, just enough to wet your soles.

Just before the Bubbling, strip out of all your clothes so the weight of your clothes or friction from the ground doesn't instantly pop you. Squat in the pool so the mechanical stress on the bubble surface of going from human-shaped to spherical and possible friction from the ground you're standing on are less likely to pop you instantly.

You will be freezing within seconds once you bubblify, preserving you until the power to the room fails and the room heats back up above freezing. Although you're a soap bubble now and have no concept of time or anything, it should keep you in bubble form for the longest time among all bubbles.

Reference for freezing bubbles and popping at air currents: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cW8ZO7EBRkc

Going around the world with such a setup, minimized and put into a large plane on autopilot might be possible, but probably not with only 24 hours to prepare.